# A coordinate independent interpretation of $\vec u\cdot\nabla\vec v$ for vector fields $\vec u,\vec v$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, fluid-dynamics

I'm having trouble conceptualizing what exactly is meant by the term $\mathbf u\cdot \nabla\mathbf v$ for vector fields $\mathbf u,\mathbf v$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, say. I know that we can describe this literally as $$\mathbf u\cdot\nabla\mathbf v = (u^i\partial_iv^j)_j$$ but this doesn't exactly seem to be coordinate invariant. My difficulty is in coming up with change-of-variables formulae, since these seem fairly complicated.

Comment: Ask first: What is $\nabla{\bf v}$ for a vector field ${\bf v}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: it may sound surprising if you haven't run into it before, but whereas the analagous expression for scalar functions
$$\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla f$$
(i.e., the directional derivative of $f$) is coordinate-free, the "directional derivative" of a vector field is not (one intuition is that this directional derivative cannot differentiate the "turning" of $\mathbf{v}$ from the turning of the coordinate system.)

The analgous coordinate-free object is the *covariant derivative* $\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{v}$ which, as you might imagine from the name, does transform correctly under change of coordinates. Defining a covariant derivative requires more than just differential structure; you have to specify how vectors "translate without turning" (parallel transport) along curves in the space. If you have a Riemann metric, that is enough to pin down a canonical covariant derivative (via the Levi-Civita connection), and you can calculate it in coordinates using Christoffel symbols (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Coordinate_description) which are indeed fairly unpleasant to work with directly.

Comment: So is it true that the covariant derivative is the coordinate independent version of the thing I just described — in other words, does it coincide with the thing I just described in flat space?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine Yes. In Euclidean space with trivial metric all Christoffel symbols are zero and 
$$\nabla_{\sum \alpha_ie_i}\left(\sum f_je_j\right) = \sum e_j  \nabla_{\sum \alpha_ie_i} f_j = \sum_{i,j} e_j \alpha_i \partial_i f_j.$$

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine The object you described is the special case of the covariant derivative in flat space. Imagine walking along the flow of $u$ and tracking how the vector $v$ changes as you walk along. To see how $v$ changes, conceptually you grab $v$ at your current location, parallel transport it as you take a  small step in the $u$ direction, and compare it to the $u$ where you  end up.

Comment: Whoops typo ^^. You compare it to the $v$ where you end up.